# Closed form still showing in taskbar

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Creating a multi-form program linked to a database with login features in c#.

Tried moving between forms using show(), showdialog() and close(), dispose(), hide().

Once past the login form, the program will not properly close the forms.

It closes the form so the user can no longer access its controls, however, the 'closed' form remains completely visible in the windows taskbar and tab menus.

The user can even hover over the taskbar icon for said 'closed' form and see all the information there!

As the program will be handling sensitive personal information. I need help to stop this problem from happening.

Code from a back button on secondary form aimed to completely close the active form and open the main form.

"Curform" is defined outside the method as it is used in multiple buttons within the program.

```
Form CurForm = Form.ActiveForm;

public void Btn_Back_Click()
        {
            var MainForm = new MainForm();
            MainForm.Show();            
            CurForm.Close();        
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use directly active form instead of curForm

```
Form.ActiveForm.Close();
```

If you want to use curForm in other parts of the code update curForm when you have created the new form, like this:

```
Form CurForm;

public void Btn_Back_Click()
{
    CurForm= new MainForm(); 
    CurForm.Show(); 

    // Do some things  

    CurForm.Close();   
}
```